# File Upload warning Chrome 66 and above to be handled using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, c#-4.0, selenium-chromedriver

Chrome browser allows folder upload (using browse dialog) and recently post version 65 we are seeing a security popup which states that do you trust this site for uploading the files from folder.

This popup is causing the Automation to fail, is there any way to handle it using Selenium? like by using certain capability to bypass it or clicking it?

I already tried Alert accept/dismiss but it doesn't work as it seems that its not an alert. I also tried UIAutomation but it seems that elements are enclosed within the browser without any classname/ID's.

For the time being I have given a workaround of sending Keyboard Tab key and Enter keys.

Is there a proper way to bypass this dialog?

Any help will be appreciated.

Pop-Up Dialog screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Show code what you have tried.

Comment: you want to see the work around code that I have used?

Comment: Use Robot class to handle popup.    Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684136/automatic-download-file-from-web-page/33697951#33697951