# Unable to handle Sign-in pop-up using selenium web-driver for any of the browsers

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to hit a URL which asks for authentication pop-up which is neither a window pop-up nor a browser pop-up .

The code **driver.get("myURL")** will hang/pause unless this popup is entered with user name and password manually .
Once the credentials are entered manually , the automation script continues - the next line of driver.get("myURL").

Everywhere AutoIT and other alert methods are mentioned.But the problem is , the code never reaches the next line of driver.get("myURL") unless it is handled manually.

The same URL navigates to login web page on my local machine which I can handle using selenium webdriver without any problem as no alert pops-up.[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZP4m4.png)But the same URL opened in server machine - asks this popup to enter user name and password.

Comment: Please share your code and HTML

Comment: @iamsankalp89- I cant view page source when this sign in pop-up appears. I cant do anything except cancel the window and enetering the credentials.

    driver.navigate().to(url);
    String alertMessage= driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
    Credentials credentials = new UserAndPassword("test", "pwd");
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
The code waits on driver.get or driver.navigate.to till the signin pop up is entered or closed

Comment: This link might help you.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684136/automatic-download-file-from-web-page/33697951#33697951

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the authentication with your URL in `driver.get()`. 
To do so just add the credentials directly after the protocol separated by `:` and ending with `@` before your actual URL.

For example if your user is "user" and your password is "password": `driver.get("https://user:password@yourpage.com");`

Comment: I have already tried this which is mentioned by you . The uRL which is passed driver.get("https://user:password@yourpage.com"); will navigate to another uRL for authentication ("https://mypage.com/abc/xyz").
So , Unless and until the user name and password is not provided , the code driver.get (https://user:password@yourpage.com") will be stuck.

Comment: ty this one worked

Answer (score 0):

Found solution for this , can be handled through thread concept

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                driver.get(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        }, url);
        t.start();
// Next line of code :AutoIT or Robot or Sikuli to handle security pop-up
```